# How to run some gulp task based on a conditional

Tags: gulp

Suppose I have this in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('foo', ...);

gulp.task('bar', function () {
  if (something) {
    // how do I run task 'foo' here?
  }
});
```

Comment: How about [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if)?

Comment: @AnilNatha I guess that would work, but why is that necessary? Why can't I just use a normal `if` and then some code to run another task?

Comment: I think it's a decision by the developers to avoid gulp tasks being written with lots of if statements. The gulp piping is a clean and elegant solution.
If the tasks are massively different, seperate them into two seperate tasks.
If there's subtle difference (eg. add sourcemaps or not with minification), gulp-if is a good solution as the overall task still does the same job (minifying the code)

Comment: This is way too broad. Please specify *what* should be conditional. Using `if` is perfectly valid, in some situations (e.g. a global build flag that decides between various build modes). In other situations, you can use a conditional stream (e.g. `gulp-if`). I've also used things like [`gulp-tap`](https://github.com/geejs/gulp-tap) to effectively make a task conditional. What would work depends on the specific problem you need to solve.

Comment: @Louis, I don't think my question is all that broad. It seems quite straightforward to me, how do I run one gulp task from inside of another? The `if` barely comes into it really

Comment: @1800INFORMATION you're right, I take down my accusation of duplicity suspicion. It's not within pipe, it's calling gulp tasks manually, in ad-hoc fashion. This is a very good question by the way.

Comment: I'm floored by the criticism that this question "way too broad". How could it be any more clear and focused?

Answer (score 2):

## Gulp v3

Use deprecated but [still working](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/193#issuecomment-33277999) `gulp.run`

```
gulp.task('foo', ...)    

gulp.task('bar', function () {
  if (something) {
    gulp.run('foo')
  }
})
```

Alternatively, use use any **plugins** that consume task names as arguments, like [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) for example (which you will probably need anyway for running tasks in a strict sequence). I call my tasks conditionally this way (Gulp v3):

```
gulp.task('bar', (callback) => {
  if (something) {
    runSequence('foo', callback)
  } else {
    runSequence('foo', 'anotherTask', callback)
  }
})
```

## Gulp v4

Your `gulpfile`, that is, `gulpfile.babel.js` [for now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module), would set Gulp tasks as exported functions so you would call them directly:

```
export function foo () {
  ...
}

export function bar () {
  if (something) {
    foo()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make 'bar' a dependency of 'foo' and put the condition inside 'foo':

```
gulp.task('foo', function(){
  if(something){...}
}, 'bar');

gulp.task('bar', function(){});
```

This way bar will always run before foo, and foo can choose if it is necessary to run its own logic.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question